# Looping through a list of proxies

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently working on a function that is to loop through a list of functions and then restart back at the top once it reaches the bottom. So far this is the code that I have:

```
import time

createLimit = 100
proxyFile = 'proxies.txt'


def getProxies():
  proxyList = []
  with open(proxyFile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      proxyList.append(line)

  return proxyList


proxyList = getProxies()


def loopProxySwitch():
  print("running")
  current_run = 0
  while current_run <= createLimit:
    if current_run >= len(proxyList):
      lengthOfList = len(proxyList)
      useProxy = proxyList[current_run%lengthOfList]
      print("Current Ip: "+useProxy)
      print("Current Run: "+current_run)
      print("Using modulus")
      return useProxy
    else:
      useProxy = proxyList[current_run]
      print("Current Ip: "+useProxy)
      print("Current Run: "+current_run)
      return useProxy
    time.sleep(2)
  print("Script ran")

loopProxySwitch()
```

The problem that I am having is that the loopProxySwitch function does not return or print anything within the while loop, however I don't see how it would be false. Here is the format of the text file with fake proxies:

```
111.111.111.111:2222
333.333.333.333:4444
444.444.444.444:5555
777.777.777.777:8888
919.919.919.919:0000
```

Any advice on this situation? I intend to incorporate this into a program that I am working on, however instead of cycling through the file on a timed interval, it would only loop on a certain returned condition (such as a another function letting the loop function know that some function has ran and that it is time to switch to the next proxy). If this is a bit confusing, I will be happy to elaborate and clear any confusion. Any suggestions, ideas, or fixes are appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Thanks to the comments below, I fixed the printing issue. However, the function does not loop through all the proxies... Any suggestions?

Comment: You `return` before printing anything. This command leaves your function `loopProxySwitch()` and returns the variable `useproxy`. Try  `a = loopProxySwitch()`.

Comment: It should definitely return something, but it will never print anything within the `while` loop because all the `print`s are masked by the `return`s.

Comment: Oh wow. What a mistake haha. I didn't even think about that... Thank you both so much. I will be fixing the above post, but now that I have fixed it and ran it, the script isn't looping, it only returns and prints the first proxy. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn’t going to keep looping because you’re returning after the first loop no matter what. It looks like what you want is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is printed because you return something before printing.
The loop will break the first time condition is met as it will return a value and exit the function without reaching the print statements(functions) and/or the next iteration.

BTW if you actually want to print the returned value you can print the function itself:

`print(loopProxySwitch())`